# How do I create a BigQuery dataset out of another BigQuery dataset?

Tags: google-bigquery

I need to understand the below:

1.) How does one BigQuery connect to another BigQuery and apply some logic and create another BigQuery. For e.g if i have a ETL tool like Data Stage and we have some data been uploaded for us to consume in form of a BigQuery. So in DataStage or using any other technology how do i design the job so that the source is one BQ and the Target is another BQ.

2.) I want to achieve like my input will be a VIEW (BigQuery) and then need to run some logic on the BigQuery View and then load into another BigQuery view.

3.) What is the technology used to connected one BigQuery to another BigQuery is it https or any other technology.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO. I'd recommend taking [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and then reading [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as an introduction to how SO works, and how to effectively ask a question.

Comment: @MarkusDeibel While a concrete example (with code) that demonstrates where they are stuck would be preferable, this is answerable at a high level.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a large amount of data to process (many GB), you should do the transformation of the data directly in the Big Query database.  It would be very slow to extract all the data, run it through something locally, and send it back. You don't need any outside technology to make one view depend on another view, besides access to the relevant data.

The ideal job design will be an SQL query that Big Query can process. If you are trying to link tables/views across different projects then the source BQ table must be listed in fully-specified form `projectName.datasetName.tableName` in the `FROM` clauses of the SQL query. Project names are globally unique in Google Cloud.

Permissions to access the data must be set up correctly.  BQ provides fine-grained control over who can access, and it is in the BQ documentation.  You can also enable public access to all BQ users if that is appropriate.

Once you have that SQL query, you can [create a new view](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/views) by sending your SQL to Google BigQuery either through the command line (the bq tool), the web console, or an API.

Answer (score 0):

1) You can use [BigQuery Connector](https://developer.ibm.com/recipes/tutorials/ibm-datastage-bigquery-connector-to-write-data-to-google-bigquery/) in DataStage to read and write to bigquery.

2) Bigquery use namespaces in the format project.dataset.table to access tables across [projects](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects). This allows you to manipulate your data in GCP as it were in the same database.

To manipulate your data you can use [DML](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-manipulation-language) or [standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/enabling-standard-sql).

To execute your queries you can use the [GCP Web console](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/bigquery-web-ui) or client libraries such as [python or java](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries).

3) BigQuery is a RESTful web service and use HTTPS